# Why does OS.File.writeAtomic with encoding: "utf-16" not add a BOM to the created file?

Tags: unicode, firefox-addon

I am writing a firefox addon that saves the textarea contents to a file (I have my reasons to not use existing ones). The basic code that gets the job done is:

```
let promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(path, contents, {encoding: "utf-16", tmpPath: path+".tmp"});
```

The path and contents are arguments passed to the containing function. The file is created with the contents but there is no Unicode BOM at the beginning. What have I missed?

(FYI, opening the file with notepad and trying SaveAs shows Unicode. When re-saved as Unicode, the BOM appears correctly.)

I'm using Firefox 39.0.3 on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Wow extremely cool question, i have never ever seen non-utf-8 so this is super cool. Im eager to see answer for this.

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks. Looks like a Windows quirk, and I would have to prepend the BOM (like I already did). I hope leaving a BOM just in case wouldn't hurt on other platforms, but that's another headache for another time.

Comment: Can you show the code Im very interested in seeing some code.

Comment: The prepending is done like this `let promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(path, String.fromCharCode(0xfeff) + contents, {encoding: "utf-16", tmpPath: path+".tmp"});`. Make sure its little endian. The  main and content scripts communicate via ports. Nothing special.

Comment: Thanks I didnt know what a BOM is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BOM is not required to be present in any UTF stream–it is an entirely *optional* marker for the byte order (and a good guess for the encoding). Notepad writes a BOM because of how Notepad (and Windows in general) [likes to detect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx) UTF-16 data, but is by no means a requirement that UTF-16 files contain one.

If you need a BOM, you will need to prepend one to the text stream yourself.

Comment: Great link, hadn't seen it before.